# How much does a life sized LEGO person sculpture weigh?

Tags: building

Generally, how many pounds of LEGO would it take to make a life sized person sculpture?
Do they weigh anywhere near the same as the real person they are modeled after?

[image: Life sized people]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The image posted in your question shows the Lego brick artist [Nathan Sawaya](http://brickartist.com/).

On his [website](http://brickartist.com/about/), he states:

> A life-size human form sculpture typically has 15,000-25,000 bricks.

So, lets use 20,000 for our calculations.

Next, how much does a brick weigh, well of course it depends on the type of brick, but if we take the common 2 x 4 Brick [image: 2 x 4 Brick], [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3001) tells us that one 2 x 4 Brick weighs 2.32g.

```
20,000 x 2.32 = 46,400g 
= 46.4Kg
= 102.3Lb 
= 7.3 Stone
```

So one could say they are **very roughly** equivalent in weight.

But if anything, the Lego versions are likely lighter than their human twins. This is especially true if we consider that many of the bricks will be smaller than the 2 x 4 Brick we used in the rough calculation above. For example, according to Bricklink, the [2 x 3 Brick](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3002) weighs 1.92g and the [2 x 2 Brick](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3003) weighs 1.21g.

Comment: So that means that if you were to make a life-size Magneto, the Master of Magnetism, you would need at least 2x-3x times that many then, around like 40,000-60,000 pieces, if you take into account his helmet, his long flowing purple cape and his boots and his gloves. That's my goal, actually. I plan on giving this LEGO artist, Nathan Saway a run for his money.

Comment: Hmm, two 2x2's would weigh more than one 2x4 (2.42g) - generally the density of the element would increases as the size decreases because more of the volume is taken up by the thicker sidewalls.